# React Native SearchBar Invariant Violation error 'function expected, instead got a value of object'

Tags: react-native, search, searchbar, react-native-elements

I am using the `<SearchBar>` from `react-native-elements` and I'm trying to have it so that when the user pressed `enter` or `return` on the keyboard the project will execute a function.

here is my code

```
const CategoryScrn = (props) =>{
    const [searchAPI, results, errorMessage] = searchResults();
    const [term, setTerm] = useState('')
    const city = props.navigation.state.params.city;
    const category = props.navigation.state.params.category;

    useEffect(() => {
        searchAPI(city,category,'');
    }, [])
return(
               <SearchBar
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={setTerm}
        onSubmitEditing={searchAPI(city, category,`${term}`)}
        value={term}
        inputStyle={styles.input}
        inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
        containerStyle={styles.container}
        placeholderTextColor='white'
      />
)}
```

the `useEffect` function works completely fine so I know there isn't an issue in my API call. However when I enter a text in the `SearchBar` (sometimes before I even enter anything) the app will crash and I will be an error of

`Invariant Violation: expected 'onSubmitEditing' listener to be a function, instead got a value of 'object' type`

Comment: onSubmitEditing = {() => SearchAPI()}, perhaps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
onSubmitEditing={searchAPI(city, category,`${term}`)}
```

to...

```
onSubmitEditing={() => searchAPI(city, category,`${term}`)}
```

Think of it this way. Every time the component is re-rendered, each line of code is being run again. In your original version, this means the function will be **executed** with every single render.

In the new version, it just means the function is declared, but not run. You're just making it available to the SearchBar component to execute when the user presses the search button.

Hope that makes sense. You'll see this exact scenario come up a lot! :)

Comment: you my friend...are a genius. Thank you!